# Mac Catalyst resize window for screenshots

Tags: xcode, macos, app-store-connect, mac-catalyst

Mac Catalyst AppStore screenshots needs to be specific sizes and 16:10 aspect ratio. How can I easily resize the window to one of these sizes? I tried an Apple Script, but it says it can't set the bounds, even though the same script works for apps like Finder.

Answer (score 3):

You could set the minimum/maximum window size to be the desired size you need in the Scene Delegate as so:

```
window?.windowScene?.sizeRestrictions?.maximumSize = CGSize(width: 1280.0, height: 800.0)

window?.windowScene?.sizeRestrictions?.minimumSize = CGSize(width: 1280.0, height: 800.0)
```

Set it to this size or one of the other allowed sizes here: https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/devd274dd925

Comment: CGSize(width: 1724, height: 1023) is the correct size for me to get 2880x1800 screenshots on my MBP @ default scale

Comment: @JBlake you sir are a legend. Thank you.

Comment: +100 @JBlake FTW